# Cannot build relations in Room database

Tags: android, sql, kotlin, android-room

I have a problem with my Room database. It consists of 2 tables "cast", "movie" and one-to-one relation "movie_cast". When I try to build a project the following errors occur:

```
error: Entities cannot have relations. 
public final class MovieWithCastDbModel {

error: An entity must have at least 1 field annotated with @PrimaryKey
public final class MovieWithCastDbModel {
```

When I remove @Entity annotation from MovieWithCastDbModel class I get the following

```
error: Entity class must be annotated with @Entity
public final class MovieWithCastDbModel {
```

So whatever I do it tells me to do the opposite thing.

Here are the data classes themselves:

```
@Entity(tableName = "cast")
data class CastDbModel(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var id : Int,
    var name: String,
    var profile_path: String,
    var character: String)


@Entity(tableName = "movie")
@TypeConverters(IntConverter::class)
data class MovieDbModel(
    var page: Int,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var id: Int,
    var poster_path: String,
    var overview: String,
    var title: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "genre_ids")
    var genre_ids: Genres,
    var runtime: Int)


@Entity(tableName = "movie_cast")
class MovieWithCastDbModel(
    @Embedded
    var movie: MovieDbModel,
    @Relation(
        entity = CastDbModel::class,
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "id"
    )
    var cast : CastDbModel
)


data class Genres(
    @Embedded
    var genre_ids: Int

)


class IntConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromGenres(value: Genres): String {
        return Gson().toJson(value)
    }
    @TypeConverter
    fun toGenres(value: String): Genres {
        return Gson().fromJson(value,Genres::class.java)
    }
}
```

What could be a problem?

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says. Entities cannot have @Relation annotation.

A relation is not actually defined within a table (@Entity annotated class), they are independent unless you say otherwise by using Foreign Key constraints to enforce referential integrity (that children must have a parent).

Rather if you want to use a relationship, then you create a POJO class that can combine the data of the related tables.

What you have is a Cast table and a Movie table. The MovieCast table appears to be what is called an associative table (mapping table, reference table and other names). It caters for a many-many relationship. That is a Movie can have many related casts and a cast can be related to many Movies.

So for MovieWithCastDbModel you want something like:-

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "movie_cast",
    primaryKeys = ["movieIdMap","castIdMap"],
    /* Optional Foreign Key constraints */
    foreignKeys = [
        /* A MovieId MUST be a value of an existing id column in the movie table */
        ForeignKey(
            entity = MovieDbModel::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["movieIdMap"],
            /* Optional (helps maintain referential integrity) */
            /* if parent is deleted then children rows of that parent are deleted */ 
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            /* if parent column is changed then the column that references the parent is changed to the same value */
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = CastDbModel::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["castIdMap"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class MovieWithCastDbModel(
    var movieIdMap: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    var castIdMap: Int
)
```

- probably better to call it MovieCast or MoviesCastMap rather than MovieWithCast.

Now to allow MoviesWithCast's to be extracted you then have a POJO using @Embedded for the MovieDbModel and an @Relation that defines the association table.

So something like:-

```
data class MovieWithListOfCast(
    @Embedded /* The parent */
    var movie: MovieDbModel,
    @Relation(
        entity = CastDbModel::class, /* The class of the related table(entity) (the children)*/
        parentColumn = "id", /* The column in the @Embedded class (parent) that is referenced/mapped to */
        entityColumn = "id", /* The column in the @Relation class (child) that is referenced (many-many) or references the parent (one(parent)-many(children)) */
        /* For the mapping table */
        associateBy = Junction(
            value = MovieWithCastDbModel::class, /* The class of the mapping table */
            parentColumn = "movieIdMap", /* the column in the mapping table that maps/references the parent (@Embedded) */
            entityColumn = "castIdMap" /* the column in the mapping table that maps/references the child (@Relation) */
        )
    )
    var castList: List<CastDbModel>
)
```

If you then have a function in an @Dao annotated interface/asbtract class such as

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM movie")
fun getAllMoviesWithCastList(): List<MovieWithListOfCast>
```

The it will retrieve all the Movies with the related cast, as a list of MovieWithListOfCast objects (one per movie).

Room uses the annotations within the MovieWithListOfCast to extract ALL of the related cast. It does this with an underlying query run for each Movie and hence why @transaction should be used.

Comment: Thank you so much! One more quick question. If I have 1 movie and want to get a list of casts should I use the following function? 

@Query("SELECT * FROM 'cast' WHERE id = :movie") 
fun getAllCastAssociatedWithMovie(movie: Int): List<MovieWithListOfCast>

Comment: @Alex20280 yes.